# Patch SUPEE 11086

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

My Magento version is 1.9.2.2

Which file should I choose between the below given options?

> 1. PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2019-03-26-03-03-13
> 2. PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2019-03-26-03-03-50

It's not clear to me..

Comment: may be not useful any one because your magento version no patch is realese so 
http://prntscr.com/n4kvss also check your website in https://www.magereport.com/ and check which security patch is need

Answer (score 1):

Choose `PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2019-03-26-03-03-50`

Comment: explain why please

Comment: This patch is applicable for Magento versions 1.9.1.1 to 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 1):

For Magento version 1.9.2.0 to 1.9.2.4 You need to choose `PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2019-03-26-03-03-50`

If you compare both the patches you will find that in patch `PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2019-03-26-03-03-13` on line number 302 it is looking for the below file

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Design/Edit.php

Now in this file it is looking for the below code to be started from line number 71

```
     public function getDeleteUrl()
     {
-        return $this->getUrl('*/*/delete', array('_current'=>true));
+        return $this->getUrlSecure('*/*/delete', array(
+            'id' => $this->getDesignChangeId(),
+            Mage_Core_Model_Url::FORM_KEY => $this->getFormKey()
+        ));
     }
```

But from Magento version 1.9.2.0 to 1.9.2.4 the above code is starting at line number 75 which is given here into the `PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2019-03-26-03-03-50` at line number 302

So if you will apply the below patch it will not work because it will not be able to find the above code on the line 71.

> PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2019-03-26-03-03-13

You need to apply the below patch file because it is looking for the above code to be started from the line 75 & from magento version 1.9.2.0 it is present on the line 75.

> PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2019-03-26-03-03-50

There could be other differences also present I have just compared this one for this time you can check it at your end. You can refer the below file for verifying my answer

[magento version 1.9.2.2](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.2.2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Design/Edit.php/#L75-#L80)

[magento version 1.9.2.0](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.2.0/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Design/Edit.php/#L75-#L80)

[magento version 1.9.1.0](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Design/Edit.php/#L71-#L76)