# SUPEE-11086 magento 1.9.3.7

Tags: magento1.9.3.7, supee-11086

I want to install patch SUPEE-11086 in the Magento 1.9.3.7. I am not sure it will work or not because it is available with the new version 
PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.3.10_v1.sh (0.06 MB). Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267940/patch-supee-11086/267953#267953) for deciding that whether it will work for you or not

Comment: yes @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI

Comment: Yes did you find the solution for it do my comment was helpful?

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI so i can install this patch with magento 1.9.3.7 is it ok?

Comment: Yes you can install it but before that you [refer this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267490/security-patch-supee-11086-possible-issues).